# assert _backend in {'theano', 'tensorflow'} AssertionError

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano, keras

I'm trying to run [this code](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/7eb39b44eb9e16e59632d25fb3119975), but getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier_from_little_data_script_3.py", line 39, in <module>
    from keras import applications
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import backend as K
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    assert _backend in {'theano', 'tensorflow'}
AssertionError
```

I tried looking for a reason for this error, but couldn't find a solution. How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT 1**

This is the `keras.json` file:

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "tf",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tf"
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have changed the backend to `tensorflow`, but get the following error:

```
ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, None, 512). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.
```

I have added a separate question for the second edit, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383114/valueerror-the-shape-of-the-input-to-flatten-is-not-fully-defined).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you print out your `keras.json` file?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Thanks for your kind reply. Sure, please see **EDIT 1** in the question

Comment: So you should change `tf` to `tensorflow` then.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Please see **EDIT 2** in my question for the error I get when changing the backend to "tensorflow". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your keras.json should look like this

```
{
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow" 
}
```

Notice the difference `"backend" : "tensorflow"` versus what you have `"backend" : "tf"`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Please see **EDIT 2** in my question for when I change the backend to "tensorflow". Thanks.

Comment: I see the edit, but I suggest accepting this answer and opening another question  with details of the new error.

Comment: Yes, sure. I have accepted the answer, and added a new question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383114/valueerror-the-shape-of-the-input-to-flatten-is-not-fully-defined. Thanks for your kind support