# ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to run [this code](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/7eb39b44eb9e16e59632d25fb3119975), but getting the following error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
Model loaded.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier_from_little_data_script_3.py", line 64, in <module>
    top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 430, in add
    layer(x)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 583, in __call__
    output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 488, in compute_output_shape
    '(got ' + str(input_shape[1:]) + '. '
ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, None, 512). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this fix](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/7eb39b44eb9e16e59632d25fb3119975#gistcomment-2031679) from the same page?

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone else is facing a similar problem, and is wondering why the error in question was thrown, I will just add more details to [@Simplicity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43383510/5695374):

As mentioned in the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/backend/), Keras has two backend Theano and Tensorflow as of this writing. Theano and Tensorflow data/images have different ordering of dimensions. This orderings are as follows:

> TensorFlow: [batch, width,height, channels]
>
> Theano: [batch,channels, width, height]

If you are gonna be using the Tensorflow ordering(as is the case with the OP), you either have to :

1. Specify this in you `keras.json` config file(found in `~/.keras/keras.json` in Ubuntu). For example to run using Theano, in your `keras.json` config file, you put the following lines:

   ```
   "image_dim_ordering": "th" 

   "backend": "theano"
   ```
2. Specify the relevant backend you will be using on your code, eg:

   ```
   from keras import backend as K
   K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
   ```

The OP is using Tensorflow, thus he/she needs to make sure that the data is in the form `[batch, width, height, channels]`, hence you have to change the define the input tensor as:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(150,150,3))
```

And the model as:

```
model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)
```

Had the OP been using Theano backend then the input tensor would have to be defined as:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 150, 150))
```

*-Notice that the channel is the first argument in this case.*

And the model defined the same way as:

```
model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)
```

Just to reiterate; I'm merely adding some clarity to why/how @Simplicity's answer worked for him.

I hope this helps someone :).

Sources:

- https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3850
- https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5257
- https://keras.io/backend/

Answer (score 1):

I  also had the same error and did not fix even after changing keras.backend and image_dim_ordering. Seems that the error was in the Maxpool layer where the pool_size argument should be written. Instead of this:

```
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
```

It should be this:

```
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @umutto's comment, those were the changes that solved the issue:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(150,150,3))
# build the VGG16 network
model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error it was because I hadn't specified the `input_tensor` or the `input_shape` of the pre-trained model I was using, similar to what @Simplicity mentioned.